# What Flying mounts can I get and where do I get them? 

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, I have a level 67 human warlock and have just purchased Expert Riding.

Does this mean I can now purchase a flying mount from somewhere - and if so, what can I buy, and where can I buy it? It isn't offered by my trainer, which my previous mounts were.

For context, I have a Wrath of the Lich King account and am at version 4.0.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warlocks do not get special class specific flying mounts. Instead, you can buy a faction specific flying mount from a vendor which should be located somewhere near the trainer who taught you flight.

For instance, in Stormwind, on the platform where the flight trainer is located, the [mount vendor](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=43768) is the third NPC on your left (just past the flight master). He should offer griffons in a variety of colors.

For the sake of completeness: [Here is a list of all Flying Mounts, click on any one to see where it is obtained.](http://www.wowhead.com/items=15.5.2) Most of those are Epic Flying mounts that will require you train 300 Flying at a cost of 5000 gold. For 225 (Expert) Riding, [This is the entire list](http://www.wowhead.com/items=15.5.2?filter=qu=3). Note that the Broom is a limited duration holiday item, the X-51 Nether Rocket is from the trading card game, and the remainder are faction specific.

[Listed here](http://www.wowhead.com/item=25472), you'll find the 5 vendors that will sell the three mounts you can use right now. They're located in [Stormwind](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=43768), [Dalaran](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=32216), [Honor Hold](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=35101), [Valiance Keep](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=35131), and [Wildhammer Stronghold in Shadowmoon Valley](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=20510).

Comment: Additionally in the "special cases" listed above, the Spectral Steed is an all purpose mount that scales with your riding level and is purchasable through the Online BattleNet Store.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I am airborn at last!

Comment: Don't forget about the profession specific mounts -- Tailoring has Carpets, Alchemy turns into a dragon, and Engineering nets you a Gyrocopter.